# Adobe Livecycle ES3 saving issue - file keeps getting larger

Tags: adobe, livecycle

I have been working on a form in Adobe Livecycle ES3.

I started with a file that was approx. 1 MB in size.

I realized that every time I saved the file it got larger by approx. 1-2 MB.

This happens even if I just save the file as a new name without doing any editing.

I ended up with a 45 MB file size and I really did not change that much to the form design.

I am new to this program, and cannot find anything online to explain this behavior.

I am thinking that the program is saving some kind of history buffer?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit to Answer Questions asked below:

1) The form is stored locally

2) The only option is to save as a PDF. The form is based off of a PDF imported document.

3) Can I change to XDP when it is imported background artwork?

4) The XML does not appear to be doubling up info.

I found an article yesterday that talks about the file size growing each time you save it with Livecycle. The adobe guy seemed to say that it was life and that there was nothing you could do about it. Seems a little weird to me. I don't know if I have really given you anything new here. I am very frustrated with it.

Thanks
SUB

Answer (score 0):

To start off, I need to ask you if your form is stored locally on your machine or are you editing a copy of the form saved on the LiveCycle server itself ?

1. If your form resides on the server, download a copy of the form on your machine and try your tests on it to see if the file size increases every time you save it on your machine. Do let me know how your tests go in this scenario.
2. If you are working on a form design on your machine, are you saving your form as a PDF or an XDP ?
3. If you are saving your form as a PDF, save it as an XDP.
4. If you are saving your form as an XDP, open it up in either the XML editor in LiveCycle designer or just use a text editor to view its contents.

I have seen issues in the past where (and its a bug btw) LiveCycle Designer repeats the same design time XML tags mulin the form. If this is the case in your form, you can simply do a find and replace to remove them.

Hope this helps. Please let me know how your tests go and if you have any more questions about LiveCycle.

Thanks,

Armaghan.

Comment: 1) The form is stored locally

Comment: 2) The only option is to save as a PDF. The form is based off of a PDF imported document. 3) Can I change to XDP when it is imported background artwork? 4) The XML does not appear to be doubling up info.  --- I found an article yesterday that talks about the file size growing each time you save it with Livecycle. The adobe guy seemed to say that it was life and that there was nothing you could do about it. Seems a little weird to me. I don't know if I have really given you anything new here. I am very frustrated with it. Thanks for your help. SUB

Comment: Hmm...seems to be a really weird issue. is there any way I can have a sample PDF that outlines this behavior ? I would be able to give you more feedback based on my review of the PDF. I'm pretty sure I will be able to solve this issue for you if you send me a sample.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue quite often, in fact today I had a file which jumped from 1.5mb to 188mb.
Having gone through the Adobe site it appears that there is no definite reason for it, but it appears to happen more when you embed fragments into the form or are using a lot of tables.

Anyway the quickest fix is to go into the XML view and search for 'aped'  This will usually find a line with something like:
    
Simply do a find/replace on the full line (leave the replace with blank).

Do this for:

Once complete go back into design view and save it.  You should see the file size decrease.

Comment: Thanks Steve. The search for 'aped' did not find anything. I am still stuck on this. I decided to start this form from scratch in Livecycle and saving as XPD file which has dramatically helped. The only thing is now I have to completely rebuilt the while document... which is quite big and detailed. I is very frustrating that Adobe using two different languages to make forms and allows them to 'blend' poorly. It would be better to just not allow import of fields when this issue is known.

Comment: I agree, for such an important piece of software it's very buggy and seems to follow very little logic.
If you have a copy of the form I could take a look if it would help.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue. I found a way around it, but you need to have a copy of the original file.

```
1. From the bloated file, copy the XML from the XML Source window in LiveCycle Designer.
2. Open the original PDF in LiveCycle Designer.
3. Replace the XML in the XML Source window with the XML on the clipboard.
4. Save.
```